# Java : How to find out the reason / cause for Web Socket disconnect

Tags: java, jsp, websocket, jetty

We are using Socket based implementation in our Application and below is the class that is responsible to do the work .

```
public class TestWebSocket  implements WebSocket, WebSocket.OnTextMessage 
{
// Overriden onConnect
// Overriden onDisconnect 
// Overriden onMessage
// Overriden onClose
}
```

This is working fine , means its able to receive the **data** and send it to the **front end** to display .

My question is that , Whenever there is an `onDisconnect`  method called , we are not sure if the user has purposefulness closed the browser (Due to which the on Disconnect  has been called )

Or

The `onDisconnect` happened due to some other reason like **network issues** or due to any problem etc.

Please let me know how to distinguish this between a disconnect due to network issue or a disconnect happened because the user purposely closed the browser? Also can we identify something in the onDisconnect method of this class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know there is no WebSocket class in the Java standard library. There are, however, multiple different 3rd party websocket libraries for Java. Which one are you using?

Comment: yes , you are right , i am using class related to jetty-websocket-8.0.1.v20110908

Comment: Highly recommend upgrading to something recent, 8.0.1 did not support the finalized RFC-6455 WebSocket standard.  It only supported early pre-draft versions of WebSocket.